# Why is this piece of code running even though I've allowed for that

Tags: php, html, forms

I do not want this piece of code running when the page actions to itself.

```
    //There was an identical id and request is somewhat real. (Still possible of a lucky guess)
    if($array['isbeingwritten'] == 1)
    {
        //The article is already being written.
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("That article is being written. Someone beat you to it. You will now be redirected.");</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="write.php";</script>';
    }
```

So I've done this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //There was an identical id and request is somewhat real. (Still possible of a lucky guess)
  if($array['isbeingwritten'] == 1)
  {
        //The article is already being written.
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("That article is being written. Someone beat you to it. You will now be redirected.");</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="write.php";</script>';
  }
}
```

That doesn't work. It still runs that code after pressing submit!! Here is my form:

```
            <form method="post" id="writearticle" action=""> 
                <textarea rows="30" cols="85" id="articlecontent" name="content" placeholder="Write the article here. Try to abide by the instructions and keywords provided." onkeyup="checkWordCount();" ></textarea>
                <br />      
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitarticle" value="Submit Article" class="submit" disabled />     

                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </form>
```

Comment: `name="submitarticle"` You have no field named 'submit', so it will never be set.

Comment: Thanks. I always get confused as to whether I should use the id or name..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the code `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
 to 
if(!isset($_POST['submitarticle']))`